# JPA/Hibernate + HQL/JPQL: select DTO with BigDecimal parameter

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hql, jpql

We are using JPA with hibernate as the implementation. Suppose I have the following DTO:

```
public class SupplierInfoDto{
   private String supplierName;
   private BigDecimal remainingFinances;

   public SupplierInfoDto(String supplierName, BigDecimal remainingFinances){
       this.supplierName = supplierName;
       this.remainingFinances = remainingFinances;
   }

   // getters / setters
}
```

I cannot seem to get hibernate to properly find this constructor. I first tried the following query (the model is more complicated than this, and I need to fetch some aggregations eventually (not directly on the entities), that's why I'm fetching a DTO instead of the entities):

```
SELECT NEW com.company.dto.SupplierInfoDto(s.name, f.remaining)
FROM Supplier s INNER JOIN Finances f
WHERE s.id = :SupplierId
```

However, I get a  `org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class` exception.

The `remaining` column I'm selecting from is stored as a float in MSSQL (I know, I know money should never be stored as floats, but this is an existing system where I cannot just change this datatype)..

As a test, I tried the following query, but with the same exception as above:

```
SELECT NEW com.company.dto.SupplierInfoDto(s.name, NEW java.math.BigDecimal(10))
FROM Supplier s
WHERE s.id = :SupplierId
```

So my question is: How do I make hibernate/JPA find the appropriate constructor for the two queries above?

**UPDATE:** The `remaining` property is of type double on the Finances entity (not my decision).

Comment: What type is the remainingFinance field/column?

Comment: Can you try including a default constructor?

Comment: @SatheeshKC I can, but I don't think that will work, because hibernate will probably not be able to figure out which constructor arguments belongs to which getter/setter pair. If I add a constructor without the BigDecimal argument, and remove that parameter from the query also, it works correctly. So I think its a type issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure why the BigDecimal ctor is not being recognised but you could overload your constructors

If you had

```
public SupplierInfoDto(String s, Double d) {
   this(s, new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(d)));
}

public SupplierInfoDto(String s, BigDecimal bd) {
   //set fields
}
```

Not that if you use the BigDecimal double constructor the number is based on a double so can still have rounding errors. It is usually best to use BigDecimal string contstrctor

For example

```
new BigDecimal("0.1")
```

is more precise than

```
new BigDecimal(0.1d)
```

[This](http://rayfd.me/2007/04/26/the-evil-bigdecimal-constructor/) article explains this

Comment: Yes this should work. But as you point out, the rounding problem is still present which is what I'm trying to avoid. Can I cast/convert to another type in HQL?

Comment: @MortenJacobsen just updated answer to have String.valueOf(...) This may help although if the source in the DB is not good you cannot expect the java to be good without applying some rules

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```sql
CAST(f.remaining AS big_decimal)
```

According to https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/reference/en/html/queryhql.html：

> cast(... as ...), where the second argument is the name of a ***Hibernate type***, and extract(... from ...) if ANSI cast() and extract() is supported by the underlying database

And https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/type/package-summary.html

> BigDecimalType ***big_decimal***: A type that maps an SQL NUMERIC to a java.math.BigDecimal

Answer (score 0):

```
class named X  with a constructor that takes two parameters. The types of the parameters from the SELECT clause must match the signature defined in the class.

Syntax for the SELECT clause:

select_clause ::= SELECT [DISTINCT] select_expression
    {, select_expression}*
    select_expression ::=
    single_valued_path_expression |
    aggregate_expression |
    identification_variable |
    OBJECT(identification_variable) |
    constructor_expression
    constructor_expression ::=
    NEW constructor_name ( constructor_item {, constructor_item}* )
    constructor_item ::= single_valued_path_expression |
    aggregate_expression
    aggregate_expression ::=
    { AVG | MAX | MIN | SUM }
    ([DISTINCT] state_field_path_expression) |
    COUNT ([DISTINCT] identification_variable |
    state_field_path_expression |
    single_valued_association_path_expression)
```

Comment: FYI, JPA 2.0 specification talks about this in the section 4.8 SELECT Clause

Comment: This is'nt really helpful.. The syntax is not a problem since the query passes. I'm wondering why hibernate cannot pickup on the BigDecimal parameter properly.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use java.lang.Number as the constructor parameter and create the BigDecimal field based on the .floatValue() / doubleValue() of the parameter.