# Query with nested constructor

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

When i try this query with nested constructor with my custum DTO.

```
select new DTO.foo ( new DTO.boo( ... ) , new DTO.boo( ... ) ) from Foo
```

I got this error :

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: 
unexpected token: new near line 1, column 23 [ select new DTO.foo ( new DTO.boo( ... ) , .....
```

**SOLUTION**
Since we cannot have a constructor within a constructor because it's illegal in `JPQL` We resolve this issue by following the same approach over here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/12742926/1383538

Comment: Can you add the quer made by hibernate from log

Comment: it's a `QuerySyntaxException` so there is no generated hibernate query yet

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is illegal `JPQL`, as per the `JPQL BNF` notation

```
constructor_expression ::= NEW constructor_name ( constructor_item {, constructor_item}* )
constructor_item ::= single_valued_path_expression | scalar_expression | aggregate_expression |
    identification_variable
```

You cannot have a constructor within a constructor (i.e `constructor_item` cannot be a `constructor_expression`). See the `JPA` spec

Comment: Any ideas on how to go around it?